# How can I customize the pager arrows &rarr and larr in bootstrap pager?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I'd like to customize the arrow to my mock up needs:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cddeh.png

I need it bolder and smaller. But I don't know how I could possible customize it. Could someone tell me how I can customize the arrows?

```css
.pager>li>a {
  color: black !Important;
  border-radius: 200px;
}

.pager>li>a.right-arrow {
  margin-left: 330px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #9ecaed;
}

.pager>li>a.left-arrow {
  margin-right: 330px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #9ecaed;
}

.number {
  color: black !Important;
  border-color: white !Important;
  padding: 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <ul class="pager">
    <li><a href="#" class="left-arrow">&larr;</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="number">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="number">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="number">3</a></li>
    <li class="number">...</li>
    <li><a href="" class="number">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="number">8</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="number">9</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="right-arrow">&rarr;</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a different character, different font or an image. How else do you think you can do it?

Comment: How can I use an image with the pager arrows? I failed to do so. I tried font change it doesnt have an effect

Comment: It's just an HTML tag `<img src="my-left-arrow.jpg" />`

Comment: How can I make the border around the arrow img more circular and how can I adjust the size of the arrow the best way to the way I need it? I really need this information to actually shape it the way I need

Comment: I think you need to go and do some basic HTML/CSS tutorials, you're asking such basic questions I'm afraid.

Comment: Look I tried border-radius 1000px but it's not getting any more circular. That's the specific problem

Comment: if you are putting an image than just put a image which is circular and by the way for `border-radius` you need this `border-radius: 50%;`

Comment: I put a transparent image and whenever I add width the image moves out of the circle. The width of the circle is okay but the width affects the image aswell moving it outside. How can I fix this?